# Tensor products and intersections of modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Is it true that $A\otimes_{\Bbbk} B \cap B \otimes_{\Bbbk} A = B\otimes_{\Bbbk} B$ if $B \subset A$ are $\Bbbk$-modules over a ring $\Bbbk$?.
It works for $\Bbbk$ a field.
Does it work in any other case?

Comment: In general, this doesn't make much sense, since $B \otimes B$ is not a submodule of $A \otimes B$ unless some things are flat or $B$ is a direct addend of $A$. Of course, if $B$ is a direct addend of $A$, then the question does make sense and has a positive answer (easy). It's an interesting question when some flatness conditions are imposed but $B$ is not a direct addend of $A$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Even in the totally flat case, if $A = \mathbb k$ and $B$ is an ideal of $A$, then this is true if and only if the ideal $B$ is idempotent, which happens very rarely. So even for locally free modules over a principal ideal domain, this can fail.

Comment: Probably it deserves to have a look at Brzezinski, Wisbauer, "Corings and Comodules", paragraph 40.16: Intersection property.